# SQL- Distinct Count (SQL Developer)

Tags: sql, oracle, count, distinct

I need to count the number of test steps in each test case.

- The table is called `Test_Step`
- The Test case has a `Test_Case_ID`
- The table has a column `Test_Step_Number`

I would like to get an answer that shows me `NUMBER` of test steps for each test case (`Test_Case_ID`).

I would like the column to be called "Number_Of_Steps"

So far I have this, but it not functional

```sql
Select Count(
         Distinct
         (STANDARD_HASH(test_case_id, Test_step_nuber))
         + STANDARD_HASH (Reverse(test_case_id), REVERSE(Test_step_nuber))
       )
from   test_step AS "Number_Of_Steps" ;
```

Comment: What is all the hashing for?  It seems totally irrelevant to your question.

Comment: It was an attempt that I found in some of the other forums. You are right....it was irrelevant to this case

Answer (score 1):

```
select Test_Case_Id, count(*) as Number_Of_Steps
from Test_Step
group by Test_Case_Id
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to alias the computed column (not the table) and, if you want it for each `test_case_id` then, you need to use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT test_case_id,
       COUNT( DISTINCT test_step_number ) AS Number_of_steps
FROM   test_step
GROUP BY test_case_id;
```

I have no idea why you are hashing and reversing the columns.